# Best practice to setting default value for GridViewComboBoxColumn (autocomplete)

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

Hi I'm currently working on a GridViewComboBoxColumn (which is used as an autocomplete column). I'm wondering if there is a best practice way to set a default value there (so that new entries are set to a default value)?

Answer (score 1):

When adding new row, RadGridView will throw the DefaultValuesNeeded event in order to allow you to specify the default values for cells in the new row. This is the place where you can set the default value for the combo column as well. Here is an example:

```
    void radGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells["ComboColumn"].Value = 5;
    }
```

More information about this can be found in the [Telerik UI for WinForms documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-rows-new-row.html).